# Why is my MacBook showing a white flash sometimes?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

When my MacBook is connected to my external 4K screen and dock, it sometimes randomly flashes a white overlay for a short amount of time. It's not a hardware issue, as the white overlay has rounded corners, does not extend all the way to the edges of the screen, and is an animated transparent overlay. It looks like an animation that could be used to indicate a screenshot was just made. It takes less than a second.

I've already checked accessibility settings related to flashing when a notification appears, but all of that is disabled (and it happens when no notifications are coming in). It doesn't seem tied to the application I'm using at the moment and it happens seemingly randomly. I have only seen it happen when connected to this particular monitor and dock. Frequency ranges from 2 times in 5 min to less than once an hour, but rarely more than 10 times over an entire evening.

Any attempt at searching for this leads me to posts about broken screens, sudden white flashes (full screen fully white), or flickering, which this is not. The screen and dock work perfectly well besides these occasional overlays. I would highly appreciate it if anyone could tell me what it means, what the feature is called, and/or how to prevent it.

I have a MacBook Pro with M1 Pro (32 GB Memory), running Mac OS Ventura 13.5.1 (22G90).

Comment: Quick test. Switch to Finder, press cmd/opt/shift/B [which isn't a valid command by default] - does it beep or flash?

Comment: Do you have Screen Sharing on?

Comment: @Tetsujin cmd+opt+shift+B in Finder does not give a beep nor any flash. If I do this in a terminal I get the "pop/beep" but no flash.

Comment: @benwiggy Screen sharing is disabled in system settings.

Comment: OK. I just wondered whether the Accessibility  'flash screen when an alert occurs' had been accidentally enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the errors are happening specifically in enabling/using the sound output of the dock. My best guess is that because it's the audio output which is erroring/crashing, the system falls back to doing an error flash instead of the usual error beep.